# MobileConnect Short Code & Long Code options

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, sms, sendsmsactivity

Is there a way to use an existing Short Code or Long Code number to send SMS messages in MobileConnect?

Also, are you limited to using prebuilt Templates when sending text messages? Is there a way to just log in to MobileConnect and send a one-off text message to a specific customer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No option to use existing shortcode / longcode.

Salesforce Service Team will provision new numbers for MobileConnect exclusive usage.

You can use [**QueueMO API**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/using-the-mobileconnect-api.htm) to send one-off messages the most easy way to specific contacts, but otherwise you'll need to create a Data Extension with the contact(s) you want to send a single message.

As far as I know there isn't a single-send-per-contact option in MobileConnect yet, they need to exist in some List or Data Extension.